# How to migrate a post that doesn't belong here to Super User?

Tags: bug, feature-request, migration

So I ran into a [post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/422617/my-screen-laptop-lenovo-ip320-flickering-is-someone-here-to-solve-the-problem) about a Lenovo laptop that obviously needs to be moved over to Super User.

So I clicked to close it and selected the Community Specific option and then to suggest moving it to another site, but the only one available was here on *Meta.*

[image: Only Meta...]

This has happened before. Is that option only for moving things to Meta? Then why the option to then *choose* which site instead of the option being "Move this to apple.meta.stackexchange.com" as the only option?

Or is there something missing, like the option to choose which site to suggest it be moved?

Just seems odd to me and I thought I would bring it up publicly in case it is an issue that needs to be addressed, or I need to be educated...;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're referring to are so-called [migration paths](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/261196/295232). They can be set up, but since we migrated [only two posts](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tools/posts/migrated/stats) to Super User in the past 90 days,

[image]

it's fine to use the alternative method as described in the [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10249/295232):

> If the **site isn't in the list** of available migration targets, or the **question got closed without being migrated**, first read the below points and consider if migration is/was really the appropriate action (in many cases, it isn't). If you think so, you can flag the question for moderator attention and request that they migrate it for you. Simply explain in the reason which site you want it to be migrated. (Please specify only *one* site; don't list all possible sites it *could* go to.)

What you did, leaving a comment and mentioning the right site so that the OP can delete and repost it there, is also a good option.

Comment: Well two posts in 90 days is still two posts and mine makes 3... Not trying to be argumentative it just seems odd that if a post needs to be migrated *no matter how often that happens* suitable targets should be available. I mean if other targets are available maybe it would happen more often. And honestly I have never seen a post that asks a technical question that needs to be migrated to *Meta.*

Comment: Not a technical question, no, but users do post [other questions](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.apple/query/1423792/posts-migrated-from-main-site) which need to be migrated to Meta. And that's true for every Stack Exchange site, hence the default option to migrate to Meta. I can't imagine a Super User question being asked on [Gardening.SE] or [Sports.SE], hence [su] is not a default migration path.

Comment: The [Q&A I linked to](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/261196/295232) contains some guidelines when staff will add migration paths. Even if we'd reach consensus here, I doubt they would be willing to do so. They have lots of things on their plate.